# Is there a way to resize a figure created with xymatrix?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic, scaling

I've drawn some figures using xymatrix, but they're much larger than I'd like them to be. Is there a way to resize them? I'd be happy to cut them down to a fixed percentage of the original or to a given size. I know how to change the size of the entries using the standard font size changing commands, but I really want to make the arrows shorter as well.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `\xymatrix`, you can change the row spacing, the column spacing, or both by adding the appropriate command in between the `\xymatrix` command and the opening brace.  The file `xyguide.pdf`, in section 3.3 (Spacing and Rotation), on page 10, lists the commands as:

```
@=dimen   set spacing
@C=dimen  set column spacing
@R=dimen  set row spacing
```

```
You use this as in, e.g.,
\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix@C=1em{
    {A} \ar[r] \ar[d]
    & {B} \ar[d]\\
    {C} \ar[r]
    & {D}
  }
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use `\resizebox`

```
\resizebox{width}{height}{your stuff}
```

If you want to specify only the width, write

```
\resizebox{width}{!}{your stuff}
```

wight or height can be any length like 3cm, 4em or 1\textwidth

Answer (score 5):

To change the distance between the entries using xy-pic, you need to define \xymatrixrowsep and \xymatrixcolsep to change the distance between rows and columns.  That is, the following code

```
\[
\xymatrixrowsep{1in}
\xymatrixcolsep{2in}
\xymatrix
{
A\ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[d]\\
C\ar[r] & D
}
\]
```

gives a square with A and B separated by 2 inches, and A and C separated by 1 inch.

Comment: If my diagram is of size 4×3, I only want the distance of the last 2 rows closer, do you know if there is a way to do so?